# how do I get the position in a scanner after find?

Tags: java

```
  private static String find(Scanner sc, String pattern) {  
        String Stoken;
        while (( Stoken = sc.findInLine(pattern)) == null) {
            if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                sc.nextLine();           
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return Stoken;  // return string that match the pattern
}
```

I know that somewhere before my data I need to get - i have a pattern -but I want to collect the data I need after the pattern - so maybe if I get the position of the pattern in the scanner I can substring in the scanner and collect what I need - but position is private - do I have a way to know it?

the data is different each time so i can not look for it directly

Comment: sorry, but the question makes no sense... can you provide a sample of the input data and what it is that you expect to get out of the data?

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
int startIndexOfMatch = sc.match().start();
```

?

please format your code as *Code Sample*.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. I was sure I need to write own Scanner to get position (although I'll need it anyway in future, but *now* I can write prototype without it). I prefer `int position = scanner.skip("\\G").match().end();` to be able to get scanner position in any case (e.g. if Scanner is passed as argument -- we don't know if some `next`/`skip`/`findInHorizon`/etc were already called on it).